# Twin Primes by an amateur mathematician

Tags: prime-numbers, twin-primes

> About 20 years ago in a bookstore of Tokyo I found a book titled "Twin Primes" by Seiji Yasui, an amateur mathematician. He insisted that he proved the infinity of twin primes.
>   The proof is attached to the book, but I cannot understand it. I hope the proof or disproof of the following by another person. I have confirmed their truths numerically $\leq 3000$.

His proposition:

Let $ n $ be a natural number. Denote as follows. 
$\pi (n) = $ the number of primes $ \leq n$. 
$G(n) = $ the number of composites $ \leq n$. 
$\pi_2(n) =$ the number of twin primes $ \leq n$. 
$G_2(n) = $ the number of twin composites $ \leq n$.

1. Yasui’s identity: 
   $$G(n) - G_2(n) = \pi(n) - \pi_2(n) +c.$$
   $$c = 0 \text{ or } -1.$$
2. Yasui’s $1^\text{st}$ inequality:
   $$G_2(n) > G(G(n)).$$
3. Yasui’s $2^\text{nd}$ inequality:
   $$\pi_2(n) > \pi(n) - \pi(G(n)).$$

Then,
$$\pi_2(n) > n /(\log(n))2.$$

> This is an example:

[image]

> Mathematica code here:

```
 G2[x]>G[G[x]]

array\[Pi]1[i_] := Select[Range[2, i], PrimeQ[#] &];
arraygn[i_] := Complement[Range[2, i], array\[Pi]1[i]];
int[i_] := Intersection[arraygn[i], arraygn[i] + 2];

ax1 = ListPlot[Table[Length[int[i]], {i, 2, 3000}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"n", "G2(n)"}, PlotLabel -> "Twin Primes", PlotStyle -> Red]
bx1 = ListPlot[Table[Length[arraygn[Length[arraygn[i]]]], {i, 2, 3000}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"n", "G(G(n))"}, PlotLabel -> "Twin Primes", 
  PlotStyle -> Blue]

fig1 = Show[ax1, bx1, AxesLabel -> {"n", "G2(n)(Red),G(G(n))(Blue)"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Twin Primes"]

    Pi2[n] > Pi[n] - Pi[G[n]]

pi2[i_] := Length[Select[Select[Range[2, i], PrimeQ[#] &], PrimeQ[# + 2] &]];
pi1[i_] := Length[Select[Range[2, i], PrimeQ[#] &]];
gn[i_] := i - Length[Select[Range[2, i], PrimeQ[#] &]];
ax1 = ListPlot[Table[pi2[i], {i, 2, 3000}], AxesLabel -> {"n", "pi2(n)"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Twin Primes", PlotStyle -> Red]
bx1 = ListPlot[Table[pi1[i] - pi1[gn[i]], {i, 2, 3000}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"n", "pi(n)-pi(G(n))"}, PlotLabel -> "Twin Primes", 
  PlotStyle -> Blue]
cx1 = Plot[x/(Log[x])^2, {x, 2, 3000}, AxesLabel -> {"n", "n/(log(n))^2"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Twin Primes", PlotStyle -> Green]


fig2 = Show[ax1, bx1, cx1, 
  AxesLabel -> {"n", 
    "pi2(n)(Red), pi(n)-pi(G(n))(Blue), n/(log(n))^2(Green)"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Twin Primes"]
```

Comment: What is a twin composite?

Comment: Did Yasui provide claimed proofs for any of the statements listed above?

Comment: How is one supposed to parse the right-hand side of the last inequality?

Comment: @SeiichiKirimaki trivia: curiously the book is at Amazon with the title "双子の素数" (literally "twin prime numbers") but there is no preview, only a kind of "poetic" introduction... :) https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%84%E3%81%99%E3%81%84-%E3%81%9B%E3%81%84%E3%81%98/e/B004LQN79U

Comment: Twin composites means that natural numbers m and m+2 are composites.
Yasui wrote the book “双子の素数” and provided his proofs as a kind of appendix.
You can see copies of the proofs in Japanese in my FACEBOOK.
https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=2004417549779954&id=100006351857047&pnref=story

Comment: I would be good to add those two pieces of information to the problem itself.

Comment: The last formula should be $\pi_2(n) > \frac{n} {(\log(n))^2}$

Comment: @SeiichiKirikami hope you do not mind, I have added an example from your link, it will help to understand how you did the tests.

Comment: Why is $\pi(200)=42$ instead of $46$ and $\pi_2(200)=13$ instead of $15$?

Comment: It is simply my miscounting. My Mathematica program gives the same values as those of Fabio. I confirmed yasui's inequalities to n = 3000.

Comment: @SeiichiKirikami if he examples above have miscountings, would it be possible to have the Mathematica code added into the question? (it can be added safely with the "Preformatted text" option). That would help others to verify.

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendation. I will add 2 Mathematica nb's later. The figures of their results to n = 3000 are already attached to My facebook.

Comment: Mathematica notebooks: I need time to learn to add "Preformatted text".

Comment: @SeiichiKirikami おはようございます、フォーマットを追加しました。I have added some formatting to the Mathematica code.

Comment: 追加ありがとうございます。Thank you very much for your addition. As I am a beginner of Mathematica, I think that the programs are clumsy, but discernible.

Comment: Maybe this is a good question for MO

Comment: From
$$\pi_2(n) > \pi(n) - \pi(G(n)).$$

how comes
$$\pi_2(n) > n /(\log(n))^2.$$

?

Answer (score 2):

**Incomplete answers**

---

The first identity $G(n)−G_2(n)=\pi(n)−\pi_2(n)+c$ is true. Basically

- a number is either composite or prime, except $1$: $$G(n) + \pi(n)=n-1 \tag{1}$$
- a pair $(m,m+2)$ is either twin composites, twin primes or one prime one composite (let's say $k$-pairs): $$G_2(n)+\pi_2(n)+k=n-2$$

and $$G(n) - G_2(n) + \pi(n) - \pi_2(n)=k+1 \tag{2}$$

Now, let's show $$\pi(n)=\pi_2(n)+\frac{k+1-c}{2} \tag{3}$$

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\pi(n) \text{ primes}& \pi_2(n) \text{ twin primes pairs} & k \text{ one prime one composite pairs}  \\ \hline
2 & & (2,4)\\ \hline
3 & (3,5) & (1,3) \\ \hline
5 & (3,5), (5,7) & \\ \hline
7 & (5,7) & (7,9)\\ \hline
11 & (11,13) & (9,11)\\ \hline
13 & (11,13) & (13,15)\\ \hline
... & ... & ... \\ \hline
p_{i-1} & (p_{i-1},p_i) & (p_{i-1}-2,p_{i-1})\\ \hline
p_i & (p_{i-1},p_i), (p_i,p_{i+1}) & \\ \hline
p_{i+1} & (p_i,p_{i+1})  & (p_{i+1},p_{i+1}+2)\\ \hline
... & ... & ... \\ \hline
p_j &  & (p_{j}-2,p_j),(p_j,p_{j}+2)\\ \hline
p_{j+1} &  & (p_{j+1}-2,p_{j+1}),(p_{j+1},p_{j+1}+2)\\ \hline
... & ... & ... \\ \hline
p_{\pi(n)} & ... & ...\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
or

- every row contains exactly $2$ pairs; either $2$ in "$\pi_2(n)$ column", $2$ in "$k$ column", or $1$ in "$\pi_2(n)$" and $1$ in "$k$". **Altogether $2\pi(n)$ pairs**.
- for the "$\pi_2(n)$ column", if $(p_i,p_{i+1})$ is in the "row $p_i$" then $(p_i,p_{i+1})$ is also in the "row $p_{i+1}$". **Thus column $\pi_2(n)$ always contains $2\pi_2(n)$ pairs**.
- for the "$k$ column" there are no repeating pairs.

As a result $$2\pi(n)=2\pi_2(n) + k + 1-c$$
where $c$ is either $0$ or $1$ to "balance parity of $k$".

**Note:** The original questions asks for $c$ to be either $0$ or $-1$, but this is only because I considered $p_1=2$. Original questions ignores $2$.

Now, injecting $(3)$ in $(2)$
$$G(n) - G_2(n) + \pi(n) - \pi_2(n)=2\pi(n)-2\pi_2(n)+c \Rightarrow \\ G(n)−G_2(n)=\pi(n)−\pi_2(n)+c \tag{4}$$

---

There is a link between 1st and 2nd inequalities. From 
$$(1) \Rightarrow G(G(n))+\pi(G(n))=G(n)-1 \Rightarrow G(G(n))=G(n)-\pi(G(n))-1$$
$$(4) \Rightarrow G_2(n)=G(n)-\pi(n)+\pi_2(n)-c$$
Subtracting one from another
$$G_2(n)-G(G(n))=\pi_2(n)+\pi(G(n))-\pi(n)+1-c$$
As a result 
$$\pi_2(n)>\pi(n)-\pi(G(n)) \Rightarrow G_2(n)>G(G(n))$$
and
$$G_2(n)>G(G(n)) \Rightarrow \pi_2(n)\geq \pi(n)-\pi(G(n))$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your proof. You are right. I think that Yasui’s 1st inequality is the essence of his proof of the infinity of twin primes. He may have proved it 20 years ago, but I could not understand it. I showed that Yasui’s 1st inequality was not a special one.
See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305192/conjectures-g-2in-ggn-and-g-2i1n-ggn-for-i-1

Comment: I agree Yasui’s 1st inequality is the essence of his proof. I found (no proof):
\begin{align}
G_2(n) > G(n)-\pi(n)\\
G(G(n))=G(n)-\pi(G(n))\\
\pi(n) > \pi(G(n))
\end{align}