# What is wrong with this reasoning regarding twin primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

There are infinitely many primes $p$ of the form $6m - 1$. $p + 2$ is of the form $6m + 1$. Since there is a one-to-one correspondence between $p$ and $p + 2$ there are infinitely many $p + 2$ of the form $6m + 1$. There are infinitely many primes $q = p + 2$ of the form $6m + 1$. Thus, there are infinitely many corresponding pairs of primes $\{p, q\} = \{p, p + 2\}$. Thus, there are infinitely many twin primes.

Comment: Find the error in this.  There are infinitely many odd numbers $n$ so that $4|n-1$. And there are infinitely many odd numbers $n$ so that $4|n+1$.  So there are infinitely many pairs of $(n-1, n-2)$ where $4|n-1$ and $4|n+1$.  Is there any difference in your argument and mine.

Comment: "There are infinitely many primes p of the form 6m−1".  Okay, we are going to put those in a set called $P$.  "There are infinitely many primes q=p+2 of the form 6m+1"  Okay we are going to put all *those* q's in a set called $Q$. and we are going to put all the p=q-2 in a set called $P'$ So if $p\in P\cap P'$ then (p, p+2) is a twin prime. So we know that $P$ is infinite.  And we know $Q$ is infinite.  ANd $P'$ is infinite.  But $P \ne P'$ and we don't know $P'\cap P$ is infinite.

Answer (score 4):

Two infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$ need not intersect.

Comment: "But out of these infinitely many p+2, there are infinitely many primes."  You have absolutely no reason to believe that at all.

Comment: I understand and agree with what you are saying. But what I am thinking is you start off with a set of primes $p$ that are of the form $6m−1$. There are infinitely many of these primes. Then with each of the primes $p$, associate with it a number $p+2$. There is a 1-1 correspondence between the prime number $p$ and $p+2$. But out of these infinitely many $p+2$, there are infinitely many primes. But these infinitely many primes $p+2$ are already linked with (or associated with) a corresponding prime $p$. Hence, there are infinitely many correspodning primes {$p$, $p+2$}.

Comment: Out of these infinitely many $p+2$, there are infinitely many primes since $p+2$ are numbers of the form $6m+1$.  But it can be proven that there are infinitely many primes of the form $6m+1$.

Comment: The p's so that p = 6m-1 and p is prime  form one set of numbers.  That set is infinite.  The p's so that p+2 = 6m+1 are prime form a *different* set of numbers.  That set is infinite.  BUT THEY ARE DIFFERENT SETS!!!!!!  What the have in common is that i) they are infinite and ii) they are each *some* but not all of the numbers of the form 6m-1.  Other than that, we have know nothing about what they have in common.  Certainly not that their intersection is infinite.

Comment: @fleablood How are they defined?

Comment: How are *what* defined?

Answer (score 2):

(For each prime $p$ of the form $6m-1$) there is only *one* choice for $q = p+2$, and it might not even be prime. It will satisfy $q = 6m+1$, though.

There are infinitely many primes $q$ of the form $q = 6m+1$, but there is no (known provable) reason to expect many of those $m$ to be the values for which $6m-1$ is prime.

Comment: $p$ is prime.  $p+2$ may not be prime.  But there are infinitely many of the $p+2$ that are prime.  Since there is 1-1 correspondence between $p$ and $p+2$ (meaning they have the same value of $m$), then we have infinitely many corresponding pairs of primes {$p$, $p+2$}.

Comment: There are indeed infinitely many $p+2$ that are prime. But why should many of them be the ones where $p$ is prime?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar scenario:

There are infinitely many numbers of the form $6m-1$ which are divisible by $5$. And there are also infinitely many numbers of the form $6m+1$ which are divisible by $5$. But there are not infinitely many pairs $(6m-1,6m+1)$ which are both divisible by $5$. (In fact there are *no* such pairs, because $6m-1$ and $6m+1$ differ by $2$, so they can't have a common factor of $5$. But that isn't as important right now.)

Here is another similar one:

There are infinitely many numbers of the form $6m-1$ which are divisible by $7$. And there are also infinitely many numbers of the form $6m+1$ which are divisible by $7$. But there are not infinitely many pairs $(6m-1,6m+1)$ which are both divisible by $7$.

In general, for any property $P$, even if it is true that there are infinitely many $6m-1$ with property $P$, and infinitely many $6m+1$ with property $P$, it doesn't necessarily follow that there are infinitely many pairs $(6m-1,6m+1)$ that both have property $P$.

There could be "bad luck", if the values of $6m+1$ that have property $P$ are "interleaved" with the values of $6m-1$ that have property $P$, instead of "lining up".

Nobody knows if the property $P$ of *primeness* exhibits "interleaving" or "lining up" behavior. The Twin Prime Conjecture is that it "lines up" for infinitely many pairs $(6m-1,6m+1)$. But for now that is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ but the set of all primes.  Let $S$ be the set of all numbers that are $2$ less than a prime.

There are an infinite numbers of $p+2$ where $p \in P$.  And there are an infinite numbers of $p+2$ where $p \in S$.  But the $p$s that are in $P$ may be completely different than the $p$s that are in $S$.

Yes for ever $p \in P\cap S$ we will have $p, p+2$ are a prime pair.  But we have utterly no reason to believe $P\cap S$ is infinite.

Replace "prime" in your argument with "is a multiple of 4":

There are infinitely many $\color{gray}{\text{primes}}$ $\color{blue}{\text{multiples of 4}}$ p of the form $\color{blue}5m−1$. p+2 is of the form $\color{blue}5m+1$. Since there is a 1-1 correspondence between p and p+2 there are infinitely many p+2 of the form $\color{blue}5m+1$. There are infinitely many  $\color{gray}{\text{primes}}$ $\color{blue}{\text{multiples of 4}}$ q=p+2 of the form $\color{blue}5m+1$. Thus, there are infinitely many corresponding pairs of  $\color{gray}{\text{primes}}$ $\color{blue}{\text{multiples of 4}}$ {p, q} = {p, p+2}. Thus, there are infinitely many twin  $\color{gray}{\text{primes}}$ $\color{blue}{\text{multiples of 4}}$.

But we no darn well there are $0$, not infinite, number of multiples of 4$ pairs.

======

Actually here is a paraphrase of you argument.

Let $J =\{6m - 1|m \in \mathbb N\}$, $K=\{6m+2|m\in \mathbb N\}$ and let $j:J\to K$ via $j(n) = n+2$ by a bijection.

Let $P_1 = \{p\in J|p \text{ is prime}\}$ and $Q_1 = j(P_1) = \{j(p)|p \in P_1\}$.  $P_1$ is infinite and in 1-1 corespondence with $Q_1$.

Let $P_2 = \{p \in J|j(p) = p + 2 \text{ is prime}\}$ and $Q_2 = j(P_2) = \{q \in K| q \text{ is prime}\}$.  $Q_2$ is infinite and in 1-1 corespondence with $P_2$.

Let $P_3=\{p \in P_1|j(p) + 2 \in Q_2\}$ and $Q_3=\{q=j(p)=p+2|q \in Q_2; p \in P_1\}= j(P_3)$.  $P_3$ and $Q_3$ are in $1-1$ corespondence and for any $p \in P_3$ the pair $\{p, j(p)\}$ are a pair of twin pairs

Your argument is as follows:  $P_3 \subset P_1$ which is infinte;  $Q_3 \subset Q_2$ which is infinite.  $P_3$ and $Q_3$ are in 1-1 corespondence.  And they are both subsets of  infinite sets.  Hence they are infinite.

Which simply doesn't work.  In calling everything $p$ and $p+2$ and noting different sets wer infinite and in 1-1 corespondence of different sets, you simple got confused and wrongly assumed the wrong set coresponded to the wrong sets.

Answer (score 0):

All you've done is assume that $p+2$ is prime.  So if you have $p := 6k - 1$, your assumption fails for $k = 4$, although $6k - 1 = 23 \in \mathbb{P}$ you should immediately see that $6k + 1 = 25 \not \in \mathbb{P}$.  Those are two different sets you have that are formed independently of each other.

I might refer you to these:

[Prime Gaps in Residue Classes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307461/asymptotic-distribution-of-prime-gaps-in-residue-classes/2310270#2310270)

[...De Polignac Sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311652/im-trying-to-find-the-longest-consecutive-set-of-composite-numbers/2313788#2313788)

[Asymptotic Expression...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2334540/asymptotic-expressions-of-pi-2n-pi-4n-and-pi-6n/2335049#2335049)

so that you understand that we define these two sets similarly.  They have the same asymptotic, but the underlying structures are completely different.