# The number $G_{3}(n)$ of composite pairs $(m, m+3)$

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a natural number. Denote as follows.

$\pi(n) = $ the number of primes $(p)$ with $p\le n$.

$G(n) = $the number of composites $(m)$ with $m\le n$.

$G_{3}(n) = $ the number of composite pairs $(m, m+3)$ with $m\le n$.

$G(n) - \pi(n) = G_{3}(n) + R_{1}(n)$, where $|R_{1}(n)|\le 2$.

Generally, for $i \ge 1$,

$G(n) - \pi(n) = G_{2i+1}(n) + R_{i}(n)$, where $|R_{i}(n)|$is bounded.

Asymptotic expression: $G_{2i+1}(n)$ is given as $n – 2n/log(n)$.

I hope that a rigoruos proof will be given.

Comment: Does composite pair just mean $m$ and $m+3$ are both composite?

Comment: Yes. m and m+3 are composites.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is quite easy to evaluate $G_{2i+1}(n)$ in terms of the given functions. The pair $(m, m+2i+1)$ is not a composite pair if and only if $m$ or $m+2i+1$ is prime. Thus for every prime $p\le n$ we can construct the non-composite pair, $(p, p+2i+1)$, this gives $\pi(n)$ such pairs. Moreover, provided $p> 2i+1$, we can make the other related non-composite pair, $(p-2i-1, p)$, this gives $\pi(n)-\pi(2i+1)$ more pairs. Moreover, these constructions produce all non-composite pairs. Since there are $n$ possible pairs in general, the total number of composite pairs is just
$$G_{2i+1}(n)=n-2\pi(n)+\pi(2i+1)$$
Also we know that $G(n)=n-\pi(n)$, so $G_{2i+1}(n)=G(n)-\pi(n)+\pi(2i+1)$. We have that $\pi(3)=2$ which satisfies your first observation that $|R_1(n)|\le 2$. In fact, $R_{i}(n)=\pi(2i+1)$ is independent of $n$. Hence $G_{2i+1}(n)\sim n-2\pi(n)$ so the asymptotics just comes from the prime number theorem.

Comment: @ Will Fisher, thank you very much for your proof. I hope that you will see the following. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300762/twin-primes-by-an-amateur-mathematician

Comment: @SeiichiKirikami Looking at the problem it seems interesting. I agree that it was properly shown that $G_2(n)>G(G(n))$ implies the last inequality which implies the infinitude of twin primes. However I did not see any proof of that inequality.

Comment: @SeiichiKirikami In fact writing $G(n)=n-1-\pi(n)$, and thus $G(G(n)))=G(n)-1-\pi(G(n))=n-2-\pi(n)-\pi(n-1-\pi(n))$, and $G_2(n)=n-2-2\pi(n)$, I am inclined to believe it is false.

Comment: @ Will Fisher, I think that your expression of $G_{2}(n)$ is not right. Yasui’s 1st inequality is a very delicate one. I confirmed it up to 20,000 by Mathematica.

Comment: I'm confused then. Don't we have $G_2(20)=4$ but $G(G(20))=G(11)=5$?

Comment: @ Will Fisher, $G_{2}(20) = 8$, $G(G(20) )=5$. $G_{2}(20)$ expanded = {6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20}. 4 is not included for convenience of computation.

Comment: So $G_2(n)$ doesn't count the number of pairs, it counts the naturals that occur in a pair?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61077/discussion-between-seiichikirikami-and-will-fisher).