# How many odd twin composite pairs are there?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was wondering, if there is a formula to determine how many odd composite pairs there are until a given $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$
like $(25,27), (33,35), etc.$ 
Theoretically it can be calculated, because they consist of prime factors, and we do know how many primes there are $\pi(n)$.

The number of twin composite pairs should somehow be calculated with a combination formula, I am just wondering of there are some research on that.

Comment: I think that one can get an asymptotic relation for this, but that won't be too easy.

Comment: We need not only know HOW MANY primes there are until some limit but also WHERE they are. The prime factors of the two numbers are always distinct, so the events "$n$ is composite"and "$n+2$ is composite" are not independent. If $n$ gets large, the ratio will approach $1$ because most of the large pairs of odd conseuctive numbers give a pair of composites.

Comment: so in otherwords weed out twin composites in an attempt at leaving twin primes behind ?

Comment: There will be three kinds of pairs. Twin primes, twin composites and mixed. For example 25-27 twin composite,  27-29 mixed,  29-31 twin prime,  etc.

Comment: see sieve of sundaram.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300762/twin-primes-by-an-amateur-mathematician

Comment: Right. I have come to some similar results, and yes, my question was related to a proof I am working on on twin primes. 

Comment: There are exactly composite $846805006$ pairs below $2090000003$.

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha Using Haran's asymptotic below, the heuristic is $854760967$ pairs which is not far off the true value.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that there are infinitely many such odd composite pairs (for eg. take $(15k+3,15k+5)$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$). To find an asymptotic formula, let $\pi(x)$ be the prime counting function. Either a pair contains atleast one prime or a pair contains both composites. There are roughly $\frac{x}{2}$ pairs less than $x$, of which $\pi_2(x)$ are twin prime pairs. Mixed pairs have a count of $2\pi(x)-2\pi_2(x)$ (Two $\pi_2(x)$ are subtracted since twin pairs are to be removed, which are counted twice when we choose $(p-2,p)$, $(p,p+2)$ for every prime $p$). Thus, if $f(x)$ is the number of odd composite pairs less than $x$-
$$f(x) \approx\frac{x}{2}-\pi_2(x)-(2\pi(x)-2\pi_2(x)) \approx \frac{x}{2}-2\pi(x)+\pi_2(x)$$
Thus:
$$f(x) \sim \frac{x}{2}-\frac{2x}{\log x}+\frac{x}{\log^2 x} \implies f(x) \sim \frac{x}{2}$$